# Why am I getting the browser URL when I try to get the img src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a check to see if an image has got a url source.

```
// HTML (short version)
<div id="image-drop-box"> 
    <img class="promo-img hidden" title="Promo image" src="">
</div>

//JS
var promoImg = $('#image-drop-box .promo-img');
var missingImg = promoImg.prop('src').length == 0 ? true : false;

console.log(promoImg.prop('src').length);
console.log(promoImg.prop('src'));
```

All tough the img source is empty, it keeps returning the browser URL. Why is that?
[See the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rL2da9ef/).

Comment: use promoImg.attr('src') http://jsfiddle.net/rL2da9ef/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the `src` *property*, which is resolved relative to the document; a blank relative URL resolves to the same URL as the document it's in. If you want to know if the *attribute* is blank, look at the attribute with `attr`:

```
var missingImg = !promoImg.attr('src'); // A blank string is falsey, so !"" is true
console.log("attr: " + promoImg.attr('src'));
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rL2da9ef/6/)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm a bit confused when to use `prop` and when to use `attr`. I thought `prop` was replacing `attr`.

Comment: @Steven: No, `prop` is for accessing *properties*, and `attr` is for accessing *attributes*. A lot of properties are *reflected properties* which are a direct reflection of an attribute (`rel`, for instance, on `link` elements), but many others are *computed properties* that are computed *based* on the attribute (like `src` on `img`, `href` on `a`, etc.). Then there are others that *start out* as just reflecting the attr, but then go off in their own direction as things change (`value` on form fields). Hopefully that gives you an idea which to use when. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The relative URL `""` is resolved as "the same as the URL it is relative to", i.e. the current document.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="image-drop-box"> 
<img class="promo-img hidden" title="Promo image" src="">
</div>
```

//JS

```
var promoImg = $('#image-drop-box .promo-img');
var missingImg = promoImg.attr('src').length == 0 ? true : false;

console.log(promoImg.attr('src').length);
console.log(promoImg.attr('src'));
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rL2da9ef/9/)

Answer (score 0):

by using `.prop('src')` it returns the value but with the full domain path

so use this code it will work

```
var promoImg = $('#image-drop-box .promo-img');
var missingImg = promoImg.attr('src') ? true : false;
console.log(missingImg);
```

it will work

Answer (score -1):

It's because you get relative url. If you have `<img src="images/a.png">`, that means you have images dir under where your file is located. Now that you specify it as empty string, it means your images are located along side with current document.